# Git tags referring to different refs on local and remote

Tags: git, github, tags

I was preparing to release the next version of my repository, and was going through the regular release process of updating the version, tagging the repo with the new release number, and pushing the commits along with the new tags to github. I ran into some issues with the release process due to which I had to undo the top commit a few times and redo the tagging.

By the end of it I could no longer push the tags to remote, with following messages:

```
.masterenv)Cardassia:ASynK sriramkarra$ git push --tags
To git@github.com:skarra/ASynK.git
 ! [rejected]        v0.1.0 -> v0.1.0 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v0.2.0 -> v0.2.0 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v0.2.1 -> v0.2.1 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v0.2.2 -> v0.2.2 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v0.3.0 -> v0.3.0 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v0.4.0 -> v0.4.0 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v0.4.1 -> v0.4.1 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v1.0.0-rc1 -> v1.0.0-rc1 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v1.0.0-rc2 -> v1.0.0-rc2 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        v1.0.0-rc3 -> v1.0.0-rc3 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:skarra/ASynK.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Digging in, I found the tags were referring to different sha1s in local and remote.

Here is the repo where the original damage was done:

```
.masterenv)Cardassia:ASynK sriramkarra$ git show-ref --tags
984cb8e494f6012f7633f4254bfd710f62f719b9 refs/tags/v0.1.0
1e687ad060bc6498b751d37adcf3d271a326666f refs/tags/v0.2.0
d1ada5d67f61c42fc9ec00215ae974908ae79fa0 refs/tags/v0.2.1
8074c5cf392364bd8a2b19bba83cf6f7ad7ed015 refs/tags/v0.2.2
c63729b79fce4324e4f274eef7f07da60ddc7a8b refs/tags/v0.3.0
142c73d3079d8e498b91686bd9270d8a0e03799b refs/tags/v0.4.0
2d060dbfcba8ab4d144dd9419699dd107e2edfef refs/tags/v0.4.1
d551c33b26476c6d7ff5bf856c1badafe399e1ed refs/tags/v1.0.0
862f048d5ff7670f22b9ba52e1bdfada13e9443f refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc1
5502d5bbefd1e3954db0bf253de70c4fa523c358 refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc2
8bd4e5b349c978693012e9a89511da9c0315b7ca refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc3
```

And here is the from a freshly cloned copy:

```
Cardassia:asynk.co sriramkarra$ git show-ref --tags
b149f420d306ea34257a447040af84d1984990d3 refs/tags/v0.1.0
1403ae014708dfed0443c1220170503af82eaf0c refs/tags/v0.2.0
5a643698f1dbed49e5e893db458460e742da2447 refs/tags/v0.2.1
d7be9fd3fa01bbc295dab5075a37a76fdbdb6935 refs/tags/v0.2.2
1703183c5fa2ade578fc7f11cba3a3a6ee8e9dba refs/tags/v0.3.0
94c764fa3f711b43a208f946b6031f3e742e4f07 refs/tags/v0.4.0
9d2eadd4cf34c257ea4165c43a1313f34ba8e867 refs/tags/v0.4.1
d551c33b26476c6d7ff5bf856c1badafe399e1ed refs/tags/v1.0.0
181cdfe665bcdc49f9e70c4ff1f403a79c02180f refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc1
12ef50042d6d632116de68d064e572a1c9031507 refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc2
66c899dca7b14ae93899b32bace77dc3d3872d5b refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc3
```

How can it get messed up like this? The strange thing is the commit history (git log --pretty=one) shows the same set of commits in both branches. Can someone throw some light on what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the entire history were rewritten, like after a large `rebase -i`.
That means the tags are no longer referencing the right commits.

It would be best to:

- start back from a stable clone repo,
- add your local repo as a remote to that new local clone
- cherry-pick the commits you want to add
- push from that new cloned repo back to the GitHub [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).

Comment: The strange bit is there are no missing commits. The entire git log is the same. The problematic repo just has tags referring to totally different sha1s.

Comment: @Karra so the commits were pushed, but the tags were not. Better repeat the process (make a tag and push it) from the new clone then.

Comment: actually even that is not true. The new tag I was pushing was v1.0.0; if you see from the logs above that is the only sha1 (d551c33b26476c6d7ff5bf856c1badafe399e1ed) that is matching between the two repos. For some strange reason the older tags got hosed.

Comment: @Karra but you could set that same tag on a fresh clone, and `push --tags`  from there.